# memoir: headings numbering starting at section level

Tags: sectioning, numbering, memoir

I'm writing a set of documents using the same `memoir` based template. One particular document does not use `chapter` level heading and just `section` and `subsection` levels.

I have no chapters but the document seems to use a default chapter 0 so my sections are numbered 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and so on. How can I disable `chapter`level numbering so I get them numbered 1, 2, 3,...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `memory` class features an `article` option, but this option doesn't remove the preceding chapter number for `\section` headings (although it does so for `figure` and `table` floats). Therefore, add the following to your preamble:

```
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
```

Comment: Works perfect!!!